# Virtualbox Ubuntu 12.04 OS is Guest Mac OSX (Lion) is Host, share folder

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, macbook, macbook-pro

Ok I have the guest additions installed and setup. I have the shared directory all setup under the devices in virtualbox.

In the Guest OS I can open a terminal go to /media and type ls and see the shared folder in the list. However when I try to access the folder I am getting a permission denied error.

```
Guest Side ls -l
drwxrwx--- 1 root   vboxsf  102 May  6 02:44 sf_ubushare
Host Side ls -l
drwxr-xr-x+  3 chris staff   102 May  6 02:44 ubushare
```

Im figuring its something mac side but I could be wrong. I know sharing a single folder or multiple folders is possible. But the last time I had it done it was done by someone else and I don't remember what they did exactly.

So what I am trying to find out is what course of action might I be missing here, and is it mac side or ubuntu side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions for the guest OS show its owned by root; try

```
sudo chown -R (username):(username)  /media/sf_ubushare
```

In the vm.